# Where is a probability measure implicitly defined?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Say we have a probability measure space $(X,\mathcal F,\lambda)$ and $\mathcal B\subset \mathcal F$ is such that we know the values of $\lambda(B)$ for any $B\in \mathcal B$.

Is it known for which other sets in $\mathcal F$ the value of $\lambda$ is implicitly defined?

For example it is obvious that if $\lambda (B) = 0$ then for any $A\subset B$, $A\in \mathcal F $ we have $\lambda (A) = 0$.

It feels like it should be a well known result (or just highly dependant on $(X,\mathcal F,\lambda)$ ) but I can't find what I'm looking for.
Perhaps I'm not using the right vocabulary in my searches

Many thanks in advance :)

Edit:
How would we calculate $\lambda(A\cup B)$ if we are given the values of $\lambda(A)$ and $\lambda(B)$ ?

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal B$ (this uses that $\lambda(X)<\infty$)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Okay but could you explain something for me? If we know Lambda(A) and Lambda(B) then how would we calculate Lambda(AuB)?

Comment: We would need to know $\lambda (A \cap B)$ as well.